# Encryption apps or password managers for iPhone without cloud or Internet connection

Tags: iphone, password, encryption

Is there an encryption app or password manager available for iPhone that doesn't have a cloud connection or that can be disconnected from the cloud and the Internet?

Answer (score 1):

I use 1password (https://agilebits.com/onepassword) for a long time already. Especially because it syncs very well across all my devices :)
However you can install iPhone only app and set in the Settings -> Sync Service -> Disable Sync.